# rxjs publishReplay: reset on Error

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using publishReplay(1).refCount() to cache http requests in Angular5. This works fine - except in error-cases.

I'm swallowing and reporting exceptions from the http-source, that's why I pass Observable.of(undefined) in the code below. In that case, it caches undefined of course - but following subscribers shouldn't get that value, instead it should request against the http resource again, like there would be no cache.

My current code:

```
result: Observable<any>;
list() {

  if (this.result === undefined) {
    this.result = this.http.get(`https://swapi.co/api/people`)
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Something really bad happened", error);
        return Observable.of(undefined);
        // in that case, reset publishReplay
      })
      .publishReplay(1)
      .refCount();
  }

  return this.result;
}
```

I have a stackblitz (with shareReplay, but the same problem) to show the behaviour: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s5zuqa.
A click on "Load" should re-request the http-source instead of providing the cached object from the catch.

Comment: »but it also caches error responses« You are catching and mapping away any errors before `publishReplay` gets a hold of them; whatever error behavior it implements will thus never matter since there won't ever be an error on its source observable.

Comment: »so that it will request the http resource again next time« What is *next time*, specifically? The next subscription? Should this be refcounting or not? The question is underspecified in my opinion.

Comment: you're right. I tried to clarify my question and provided a stackblitz. As you guessed, I want following subscribers to re-request the http-resource if a error happened before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you're looking for this, right? There are two important things to note here:

1. We use `shareReplay(1)` instead of `publishReplay(1).refCount()`.
2. The `catch` has been moved to *behind* the multicast operator.

You'll see that the (faked) HTTP call errors the first time around, emitting `undefined` (since we catch it). The next time around, we run the request again, this time getting a result (42) which is cached for the third run, not causing another request.

```js
// Just to keep track of how often we sent the request already
let counter = 1;

// A fake HTTP request which errors the first time, then succeeds
const request$ = Rx.Observable.of(null)
  .do(() => console.log('HTTP Request (#' + counter + ')!'))
  .delay(250)
  .switchMap(() => counter++ === 1 
    ? Rx.Observable.throw('Error!')
    : Rx.Observable.of(42)
  );

// =========

const result$ = request$
  .shareReplay(1)
  .catch(() => Rx.Observable.of(undefined))
;

Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000)
  .take(3)
  .do(() => console.log('Subscribing to result$…'))
  .switchMap(() => result$)
  .subscribe(value => console.log('Received value: ', value));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Be cautious of using `shareReplay(1)`. It has complications with unsubscribing and ref counting.

A new config parameter is being added to `shareReplay()` to address this situation.

The issue is better explained here:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3336

As of today the new feature it is imminent, but not released.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4059

Comment: The subtleties are subtle with this one. Read carefully!